# Консолидация в DataFrame с проработкой "на лету" каждого файла перед консолидацией

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть несколько файлов в одной директории:

[image: Исходные файлы]

Где имя каждого файла в едином формате, а количество файлов варьируется:
Месяц_год
Содержимое в файлах приведено к единой форме.

Задача состоит в построении минимального кода, который  сформирует единый DF из файлов в папке. 
Суть в том, что данные из каждого файла должны дополняться столбцом "Месяц" и "Год", в которых стоят значения из имени файла, который нужно распарсить.

Как обработать каждый и потом сделать склейку всех в один - знаю, но код большой и мне приходится каждый раз подбавлять новые файлы как отдельный DF.

Исходные файлы меняться не должны, т.е при считывании на лету нужно добавлять два столбца и наполнять их.

На выходе должен получаться вот такой DF (по файлам примера):

[image: Конечный DF]

Могу предположить, что файлы примеров тут не нужны - только шаблон файла mm_yyyy

Comment: Приведите в вопросе небольшой пример входных данных для двух файлов (по 2-3 строки) в виде текста и результат «склеивания». [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример:

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

p = Path(r'C:\download\data\SO\877036')   # working directory

df = (pd.concat([pd.read_excel(f)
                   .assign(month=f.stem.split('_')[0], 
                           year=f.stem.split('_')[1])
                 for f in p.glob('*.xlsx')],
                ignore_index=True)
     )
```

Comment: Код, указанный к задаче отработал как надо - спасибо.
Из вопроса тестовые данные особо ненужны, но как элемент "Посмотреть / Потестить" для других вероятно нужен. Чуть позже прикреплю образцы примерных данных.